# Hygieia Issue: Not able to see data in hygieia build widget for jenkins

Tags: hygieia

I want to use build widget of Hygieia Dashboard for Jenkins, but not able to populate data in it.

Installed Mongo.

Downloaded Hygieia V1.2.0.

Successfully ran mvn clean compile install package.

Created application.properties in corresponding config folders for Hudson Collector.

Run hudson collector with java -jar

Run gulp serve in the UI folder

Everything appears to come up ok
I see data has been created in mongo
I can add a dashboard in the UI .

But, I can not succesffuly add Build widgets for Jenkins via the UI.

this is the widget dashboard and we are using build widget-
[this is the widget dashboard and we are using build widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTMYv.jpg)

on click of configure and adding the server and jobname , it is getting logged out. Below is the snippet-
[on click of configure and adding the server and jobname , it is getting logged out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tzPd.jpg)

Automatically it is coming to login page-
[Automatically it is coming to login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Ggr.png)

And after logging again to the widget dashboard, we are getting build widget with no data-
[build widget with no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWSMe.jpg)

Now, when I checked in db, I am getting all the jenkins jobs in collector_items.
But not able to show it in build widget.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue with all widgets in Hygieia. The only way to get it running is to let the collectors run for some time untill data is populated in the database and then restart the entire process including the UI Server and the Collectors & API service. Still if you cant see the data populated try removing the widgets and adding it again and leave the UI page as it is on the screen for 5-10 minutes, your data will be there.

This usually occurs initially when we are configuring a new collector for the very first time.